# Для чего делать do {} while (0)?

Tags: c

Уже не раз замечаю подобный код

```
#if FUSE_TRACE
#define TRACE(x...) fprintf(stderr,x)
#else
#define TRACE(x...) do {} while (0)
#endif
```

Почему именно так, а не

```
#if FUSE_TRACE
#define TRACE(x...) fprintf(stderr,x)
#else
#define TRACE(x...)
#endif
```

Насколько я понял  `do {} while (0)` транслируется в `NOP` инструкцию, но зачем она здесь?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Макросы - вещь достаточно тонкая. Представьте ситуацию, кто-то написал код (пример условный) (но лучше так не пишете именно из-за этого).

```
for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
 TRACE("ok"), s+=i;
do_any();
```

Здесь всё будет корректно работать.
В релиз режиме если мы будем использовать как вы предлагаете

```
#define TRACE(x...)
```

Произойдёт следующее, код преобразуется в

```
if (something) 
    , s+=i;
do_any();
```

И он не скомпилируется.

Так же не скомпилируется

```
expr? TRACE("y") : TRACE("n");
```

Однако, и с использованием макроса `#define TRACE(x...) do {} while (0)` есть аналогичные проблемы. Я лично использую следующий макрос в таких целях:

```
#define TRACE(x...) ((void)0)
```

Либо же использую отдельную функцию (а не макрос) для вывода логов.

Answer (score 1):

Еще, это костыль для многокомандных макросов.

```
#define macro() cmd1; cmd2  
if (cond) macro();
```

В таком случае, фрагмент будет интерпретирован как

```
    if (cond) cmd1; 

    cmd2;
```

а не

```
if (cond) {
           cmd1; 
           cmd2:
}
```

Т.е. если в макросе несколько команд без общих операторных скобок (do {...} while(0) ), то в if будет исполнена (или не исполнена) только первая команда макроса. Вторая (и остальные) будет работать вне зависимости от условий if.
К слову, поэтому для if и требуют всегда ставить операторные скобки, даже если там всего 1 оператор.