# Функция для вывода в консоль

Tags: c++

Есть некоторая программа, в которой есть многочисленные выводы на консоль различных данных для диагностики, иногда их очень много, иногда нет. Хочу сделать возможность отключения отладочной печати переменной `bool`, но получается некрасивый код в каждом таком сообщении `if (bool){cout << "blablabla";}`.

**Собственно вопрос**, как реализовать такую функцию с учетом, что переменных в `cout` может быть различное количество (1-99) и разных типов (`int`, `float`, `string` и т.д.)?

Пробовал что-то подобное:

```
void Comment(string Args, ...)
{
    тут вывод
}
```

Но надо выводить и `int` и `float` переменные и логично, что появляются ошибки...

Comment: можете попробовать сделать примерно так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519741/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-do-while-0/519742#519742 ну или что-то аналогичное, или же хотите именно функцией?

Comment: Может быть, вам нужен паттерн null-object?

Comment: думаю, вам стоит попробовать сделать аналогично реализации printf, когда одним из параметров передается форматная строка, разбирая которую мы можем определить количество аргументов и их типы ( и соответствующим образом обработать Args...)

Comment: А можете немного поподробней с null-object? Я не большой специалист в ооп =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать свой поточный логгер, который будет оборачивать std::cout (или любой другой поток). Сделать ему состоение - писать в лог или нет, и перегрузить operator<< в котором вывод в контролируемый поток будет только если флаг в нужном состоянии.
Типо такого:

```
class Log
{
public:
    Log(std::ostream& os, bool log = true) : _os(os), _log(log) {};
    template<typename T>
    Log& operator<<(const T& obj)
    {
        if (_log) _os << obj;
        return *this;
    }

    void Switch() { _log = !_log; }


private:
    std::ostream& _os;
    bool _log;
};
```

Пример использования:

```
Log log(std::cout); //Can be any output stream. i.e. file stream, string stream e.t.c.
log << "a";
log << 2;
log.Switch();
log << "A" << 10 << "\n";
log.Switch();
log << "C" << 50 << "\n";
```

Выведете

```
a2C50
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Но все же, мне кажется это не решает задачу. Ведь по сути, я переключаю лог кодом, что громоздит этот самый код и создает большое количество условных операторов (если включен, выключен то переключить включить и т.д. и т.п.), а цель сделать именно одну единственную точку для включения\выключения всего лога в программе. Ну и... Написанный вами класс для меня пока очень сложный, но я попытаюсь разобраться подробно. Спасибо!

Comment: @Neuromanser ну вообще-то лог 1 раз инициализируется. Можете захардкодить в нём `cout` вместо `_os` и выключать вывод прямо тут.

Comment: @pavel уже более менее разобрался, спасибо! Поспешил с комментарием :)

Comment: @Neuromanser 1)Данный класс является лишь обёрткой над потоком вывода, соответсвенно, вы можете создать объект данного класса в любом месте, разные экщемпляры объекта Log могут существовать параллельно и не блокируют друг друга. Создайте несколько объектов в разных местах, либо один глобальный. 2)Хардкодить что либо в таком случае довольно плохая идея.