# Зачем нужна конструкция do { ... } while(0)?

Tags: c, циклы, макросы

В библиотеке *freeglut* в файле `freeglut_callbacks.c` нашел такой код:

```
/*
 * All of the callbacks setting methods can be generalized to this:
 */
#define SET_CALLBACK(a)                                         \
do                                                              \
{                                                               \
    if( fgStructure.CurrentWindow == NULL )                     \
        return;                                                 \
    SET_WCB( ( *( fgStructure.CurrentWindow ) ), a, callback ); \
} while( 0 )
```

Не понимаю, зачем здесь нужен цикл, ведь он в любом случае выполниться всего **один** раз, разве нет?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519741/Для-чего-делать-do-while-0

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Конструкция широко используется в "функциональных" макросах и предназначена для объединения нескольких statement и объявлений внутри макроса в один составной statement. Такое объединение нужно для того, чтобы макрос можно было использовать как обычный вызов функции в ветках условного оператора, циклах и т.п. без необходимости постоянно заключать этот вызов во внешнюю пару `{ ... }`

На первый взгляд того же самого можно было бы достичь просто путем заключения самого определения макроса в пару `{ ... }` вместо `do { ... } while (0)`. Однако вариант с `{ ... }` будет обладать одним неприятным недостатком - надо будет постоянно помнить, что его тело представляет из себя `{ ... }`, а после `{ ... }` в С не всегда можно ставить `;`.

Например, если бы тело `SET_CALLBACK` было заключено просто в `{ ... }`, то вот такой естественно выглядящий код не скомпилировался бы по причине того, что из-за поставленной после `SET_CALLBACK(foo)` точки с запятой ветка `else` оказалось оторванной от своего `if`

```
if (true)
  SET_CALLBACK(foo); // <- "Лишняя" `;`
else                 // <- Ошибка: оторванный `else`
  /* что-то еще */;
```

Вот тут-то на сцену и выходит `do { ... } while (0)`. Цикл `do/while` уникален тем, что является единственной (почти) в языке С грамматической конструкцией, которая формирует блок, и при этом всегда безусловно заканчивается на `;`. Благодаря этой замыкающей `;` мы можем более естественным образом использовать `do { ... } while (0)` внутри составных макросов для объединения их в единый statement. В вышеприведенном примере с `if` `;`, указанная после `SET_CALLBACK(foo)`, будет "поглощена" конструкцией `do { ... } while (0)` и не приведет в "разрушению" целостности `if`.

Вот именно ради того, чтобы иметь возможность "вызывать" функциональные макросы через тот же естественный синтаксис, через который мы вызываем обычные функции, тело составного макроса и заключают не в `{ ... }`, а именно в `do { ... } while (0)`

**P.S.** Почему авторы языка в свое время решили настоять на включении [теоретически совсем не нужной] замыкающей `;` в синтаксис `do/while` - не совсем ясно, но это было сделано.

Comment: В некоторых случаях удобнее пользоваться GCC'шным расширением `({...})`.

Comment: В общем, костыль типичный.

Answer (score 13):

Это очень полезная конструкция. Так как макросы подставляются "как есть", то могут происходить различные чудные вещи. Допустим у нас есть такой макрос

```
#define foo(x) int x;\
x=1;\
printf("%d\n",x);
```

(пример надуманный)

И если теперь вызвать вот так

```
if (...) foo(a);
```

то это развернется в такое

```
if (...) int a; a=1; printf("%d\n",a);
```

и естественно, будет работать совсем не так, как того ожидает применяющий - объявление переменной явно не там и скобок не хватает.

В принципе можно было бы обойтись просто фигурными скобками, но конструкция с `do-while(0)` дает один существенный плюс - возможность использовать break для выхода с макроса, что ещё больше приближает макрос к обычной функции.

Comment: Точку с запятой она даёт. И вообще, дубликат же, только надо найти вопрос.